# Get php sub array from html input name

Tags: php, html, regex

I have an input :

```
<input name="subscription[login]" />
```

I'm creating a function that take an array (`$_POST` for the example) and the html name (`subscription[login]`).

It should return me a reference to `$_POST['subscripton']['login']`

So i made :

```
public static function &getSubArrayRefFromPath($arr, $arrPath) {
    if(!is_array($arrPath)) {
        throw new Exception('$arrPath is not an array');
    }
    else {
        $el = $arr;

        foreach($arrPath as $k) {
            $el &= $el[$k];
        }

        return $el;
    }
}

public static function &getSubArrayRefFromHtmlPath($arr, $htmlPath) {
    $regex = '#^([a-z]+)(?:\[([a-z]+)\]){2}(\[\])?$#i';

    preg_match($regex, $htmlPath, $rawKeys);

}
```

but i can't retrieve all the values with the regex :

i get this in rawKeys :

```
array
  0 => string 'abc[def][ghi]' (length=13)
  1 => string 'abc' (length=3)
  2 => string 'ghi' (length=3)
```

I'm probably missing something..

Answer (score 0):

The lithium framework has a very handy structure called a Set:

```
include 'Set.php'
$ary = array('a' => array('b' => 1, 'c' => 2), 'd' => 3);

lithium\util\Set::extract($ary, '/a/b')
-> array(1)
lithium\util\Set::extract($ary, '/a/.');
-> array(array('b' => 1, 'c' => 2))
lithium\util\Set::extract($ary, '/a/@*');
-> array(array('b', 'c'))
```

- https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/util/Set.php
- http://li3.me/docs/lithium/util/Set

**edit:**

For something less powerful:

```
function find(&$ary, $key) {
    if (strstr($key, '.')) {
        list($k, $key) = explode('.', $key, 2);
        return find($ary[$k], $key);
    } else {
        return $ary[$key];
    }
}

find($ary, 'a');
-> array('b' => 1, 'c' => 2)
find($ary, 'a.b');
-> 1
```

I guess you can figure out how to convert `a[b]` to `a.b` yourself (hint: it's in the comments)

Comment: ok, but that's not an answer, i don't want to use lithium to do a simple manipulation with a string

Comment: you can get that file only, or the function only, the rest of the kitchen sink isn't needed.

Comment: ok but the basic manipulation on the array, i maked it in `getSubArrayRefFromPath`. What i need is to get an array like `array('abc', 'def', 'ghi')` from string `"abc[def][ghi]"`

Comment: `explode('.', preg_replace(array('/(\[|\]\[)/', '/\]/'), array('.', ''), $key));`

Comment: that should do the trick but isn't there a more simply method using preg_replace(_all) to retrieve directly the keys names ?

Comment: much simpler indeed: `preg_match_all('/\w+/', $key, $matches)`

Answer (score 0):

Working regex:

```
'#^([a-z]+)(?:\[([a-z]+)\])(?:\[([a-z]+)\])$#i'
```

Result `def` is overwritten by `ghi` (in your example `abc[def][ghi]`), that's why you end up with only two results.

To remove the first element (which is always the text that matched the full pattern) use:

```
unset($rawKeys[0]);
```

Comment: ok isn't there any possibility to retrieve the two elements ?